# A property on exterior measures on a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $\mu:2^X\to[0,\infty]$ be an exterior measure on $X$, $\mathcal{M}:=\{E\subset X:\forall S\subset X\ \ \ \mu(S)=\mu(S\cap E)+\mu(S-E)\}$. Suppose $\mathcal{B}(X)\subset\mathcal{M}$.

Then Leon Simon *Lectures on geometric measure theory* chapter 1 section 3 remark 3.1 states that
\begin{eqnarray}
\mu(B(x;\rho))\geq\limsup_{y\to x}\mu(B(y;\rho))
\end{eqnarray}
, where $x\in X$, $\rho>0, $
$B(x;\rho):=\{a\in X:d(x,a)\leq\rho\}$.

I have no idea to prove this statement. Please tell me any idea. Thank you.

Comment: "We do not assume that $A \in \mathcal M$."  What is $A$?

Comment: Sorry that is an error.